# Visual Studio 2019 "no repositories available" for an Azure DevOps Server

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

We have an Azure DevOps server that's used as source control. I am able to open DevOps in the browser (tested with Chrome and IE) with my credentials and see all the repositories but I can't connect to it through VS.

When I go to Visual Studio -> Team Explorer -> Manage Connections -> Connect to a Project -> Add Azure DevOps Server and type in the URL of the server, the server is successfully added but it has a warning sign (yellow triangle with an exclamation mark) and if I hover it, it says "no repositories available" -- see screenshot.

Are there any more details available to me? I tried launching VS with the /logs argument but that had nothing useful. It sounds like a permissions issue to me, my user being able to connect to the server, but not having read permissions to the repos, but, my user can see everything through the browser so I am not sure what to make of this. I installed the latest VS update and am on 16.3.9.

The DevOps server is technically hidden behind a VPN, not sure if that's important. I can't open DevOps in the browser if my PC is not connected to the VPN.

[screenshot of the error icon/message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEGXS.png)

Comment: try logining online, then try reauthentication and lastly check if there are any repositories

Comment: Logging in online works great; I've tried reauthenticating by deleting network credentials in control panel. We believe that there are repositories in place since I see them online + other developers see them in their Visual Studio. We can't figure out what's different between me and other developers.

Comment: check permissions on repos

Comment: For troubleshooting, what about connect to TFS by using the VS in the server? This could know whether the issue caused by VPN

Comment: i doubt it. a vpn would still show repos, more like they are not authorized

Comment: We tried giving me super admin access in DevOps -- no luck, same issue.

Comment: What type of VPN are you using? We have found that client-less vpn solutions based on cookies/sessions does not work with VS. The symptoms is just like you describe as the vpn authentication works in the web browser but it is not available when VS makes its connection.

Comment: Pulse Secure; it does have a windows client and doesn't rely on cookies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same scenario and the same issue and I managed to solve it eventually.

Background
* Two company sites connected via company fixed VPN (not on client machine)
* Two local tfs installations (different versions)
* Visual Studio 2019

When I add the remote tfs using tfs name http://tfs01.xxx.yyy.net (port 80) it seems to work but no repositories found, only a yellow warning sign.

**Reason**
The url name http://tfs01.xxx.yyy.net/ is stored as http://tfs01/ in all local cache.
The name http://tfs01 is not found (can't ping it, not resolved)

**Solution**
Edit files in cache and change http://tfs01/ to the full url path on every occation (at least two places)
- Go to c:\users[users]\appdata\local\microsoft\team foundation\8.0\cache
- Look in LocationServerMap.xml
- Note every unique guid for your server with issues
- Find every occation of the file LocationServiceData.config in sub directories with your guids

or use the ugly solution and add the tfs server name (tfs01 in my case) to the local host file to ensure it resolves.
c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts - add new row with ip address and short name

Comment: I'm working on VPN connection and had the same problem. The ugly solution worked for me, adding the shortname domain to the host file linking it to the IP adress. If you have multiple projects in your mappings and having to replace this all the time can be tedious.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for replying. Here are our latest finds:

Domain-joined computers would present this bug, whereas non-domain joined would work fine.
Go to cmd, type systeminfo. If your domain is WORKGROUP you will be fine. If it's anything else, you might have the same issue.

This was enough for us to work around the issue without resolving it.
Just wanted to reply in case somebody runs into this in the future.